# How can I fix the 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'string')' error when trying to access contacts on Odoo?

Tags: odoo

I cannot access to contacts due to an error " Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'string')"

I just simply want to open contacts and it gives me this error

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'string')

This happened after installing the following module: Vendor Purchase Discount
by Cybrosys Techno Solutions - this module was for version 15 of Odoo and I got the 16.

I've tried to upgrade the module but to no avail.

The error you gave me was in the following file error_service.js

console.error(uncaughtError.traceback); //-> Error in this line

handleError(uncaughtError); // -> Error in this line

I have no idea how to fix it

I've tried everything but I don't know what else to do.

Help for resolve this error